# Can we access the static member of a class without initializing obects?

Tags: java

```
public class Test{
    static Another a;// without initializing i can able to access static member of Another class
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(a.i);
    }
}

class Another{
    public static int i=20;
}
```

Here I can able to the access the static member of class **Another** without initializing the object and the system is displaying the output as 20.

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Another a;// but when i declare this inside the main method system is throwing error
        System.out.println(a.i);
    }
}
class Another{
    public static int i=20;
}
Test.java:5: error: variable a might not have been initialized
        System.out.println(a.i);
                           ^
```

But when i move the declaration inside main block system throws an error. why is that?

Comment: The way to invoke static attributes and methods is using the class name, no an instance. I mean, you should get the i value this way: Another.i in both cases

Comment: when you move the declaration inside the main method then it becomes the local variable whose initialisation is only possible within the method scope which is missing. In case you have it outside the method then compiler has no way to know if initialisation will be injected from outside or not so it does not throw an error. Compiler is not sure if you would be using its static properties or instance properties or you would initialise another instance or static variable with it or pass it to another method, hence a safe way is to fail by throwing an error, which it does.

Comment: that's the whole point of static members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should access the `static` variable `i` with `Another.i`, not `a.i`.

`a.i` is valid syntax if `a` has a value, but it's confusing (since anyone who reads you code may falsely assume `i` is an instance variable). And if `a` is not initialized when you access it, the compiler doesn't allow it.

The difference between the two snippets is that here (when `a` is a `static` variable):

```
static Another a;
```

`a` has a default value of `null`.

While here (when `a` is a local variable):

```
Another a;
```

it has no default value.

Comment: But without initializing i was able to access the variable 'i' and got output as 20. system doesn't throw any error why is that?

Comment: @MD_wasim in the first snippet `a` has a default value of null. `a.i` doesn't throw NullPointerException since `i` is a static variable, so an instance of Another class is not required in order to access it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Another i
        System.out.println(a.i);
    }
```

this can be replaced with

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(Another.i);
    }
```

You are getting **error** not because the static variable `i` but **because of local method variable `Another a` is not initialized ** , Since you have not initialized a, the local variable inside a function must be intialized befor reading its value.